# Question about constructor matching and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, constructor, instantiation, implicit-conversion, object-slicing

I am doing an old school exam in preparation for my current exam and in one of the questions I am given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
  A() : m_a(17) { cout << "A_default" << endl; }
  int m_a;
};

struct B1 : A
{
  B1() : m_b(1) { cout << "B1_default" << endl; }
  B1(const A& a)
  {
    cout << "B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A" << endl;
    m_b = a.m_a + 1;
  }
  int m_b;
};

struct B2 : A
{
  B2() : m_b(1) { cout << "B2_default" << endl; }
  B2(const B1& b1)
  {
    cout << "B2_constructor_with_a_parameter_B1" << endl;
    m_b = b1.m_b + 100;
  }
  int m_b;
};



int main() 
{
  A a1;
  B1 b1;
  B2 b2 = b1;
  A a2 = b2;
  B1 b3 = b1;
  B1 b4 = b2;
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints:

```
A_default
A_default
B1_default
A_default
B2_constructor_with_a_parameter_B1
A_default
B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A
```

The task is to match each printed line with the corresponding code line in main. I have gotten all of them right except the last printed line `B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A`. The answer sheet says that this printed line comes from the `B1 b4 = b2;` line in `main()` but there is no explanation as to why this happens.

So my question is simple. **Why does `B1 b4 = b2;` print `B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A` when it doesn't match any constructor pattern in `struct B1`?** Is there some sort of weird object slicing or implicit conversion going on here? That is my best guess. I am a bit confused.

If object slicing or implicit conversion does occur. Why doesn't the line `B1 b3 = b1;` print anything? I see no difference between `B1 b3 = b1;` and `B1 b4 = b2;` except that b2 is of type `B2` and `b1` is of type `B1`. Shouldn't the same rules apply since they both inherit `A`? I am confused.

Comment: @t.niese Then why doesn't `B1 b3 = b1;` print anything? There seems to be no difference between `B1 b4 = b2;` and `B1 b3 = b1;` except that b2 is of type B2 and b1 is of type B1. Shouldn't the same rules apply?

Comment: The naming convention used here is garbage.  Rename B1 to B and B2 to C, then rename variables of type B to b and C to c.  That makes clear the types being used in the expressions, instead of making it a stupid goose hunt.

Comment: What @Yakk-AdamNevraumont said is very true. I had to read it multiple times to be sure that I was correct. If you want to understand code you make it way easier for you if you use proper naming that cannot be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why does `B1 b4 = b2;` print B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A when it doesn't match any constructor pattern in `struct B1`?**

It does that because `b2` is of type `B2`, which inherits from `A`, which makes it implicitly convertible to `A`.

> **Why doesn't the line `B1 b3 = b1;` print anything?**

Because for this line copy-constructor(which is provided by the compiler) of B1 is invoked since both are of the *same* type. In the case of `B1 = B2`, the only matching constructor is `B1(const A& a)`. So, it implicitly converts to type `A`.

Such behaviour and code is terrible and that's exactly why we should make our constructors `explicit`. Compile the above code with the following change and you will realize that it doesn't implicitly convert anymore:

```
explicit B1(const A& a) { cout << "B1_constructor_with_a_parameter_A" << endl; }
```

Comment: Soo... as I've understood it, copy-constructors always take precedence over normal constructors and that's why `B1 b3 = b1;` matches with the copy-constructor before (potentially) matching with the `B1(const A& a)` constructor... or would it not match with that constructor regardless (even if the copy-constructor was "unavailable")?

Comment: No, There is no precedence. Suppose you have an object of type `A a1`, and you create another object of type `A` like: `A a2 = a1`, copy constructor will be called. When the types are same, copy constructor is used to construct the object.

Comment: And yes, even if you delete the copy constructor, `B1(const A& a)` will not be called.